# Error in sending data to server

Tags: xcode, ios5, apple-push-notifications

**Hi , I am building my Xcode project for APNS , I faced a problem in sending the deviceToken to the local server (XAMPP) ,here is the code :**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
NSLog(@"devicetoken= %@",deviceToken);
NSString *string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
string=[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, string.length-2)];
string=[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/addtoken.php?devictoken=%@",string];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"error %@",error);
    }
}
 ];
```

}

this  error is written in console
 error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server.

**I run my app in my device , I run link in the browser with the handling data ,the server saved it !
Can you please help me out why this error is coming?
thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

Use the ip address of your computer instead of localhost.
When  you use localhost, you assume that the request and the connection are being made locally, in your case it's between an iPhone and a Server(both of them have different ip's)

Comment: It woooooorks 
thank you so much , I was stuck in this error weeks ago ..
you made my day

Comment: @Norah allohaidan When you use localhost, you assume that the request and  the connection are being made locally, in your case it's between an iPhone and a Server(both of them have different ip's)